# Knockout Change template according to dropdown selection

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to change the header and template according the dropdown selection and clicking the search button.  Since there are quite  a number of lines of code I put whatever is necessary.  I get this error `LastCPRDate is not defined`.  Below are more details of the full error message.

**Code**

```
vmSearchDetailsModel = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.SearchResults = ko.observableArray([]); // Populate the Search Results

    self.Partners = ko.observableArray([]); // Populate the Partners
    self.selectedPartner = ko.observable("0");  

    self.Filters = ko.observableArray([]); // Populate the Filters
    self.selectedFilter = ko.observable("0");  // not using this show/hide

    self.ShowAData = ko.observable(false);
    self.ShowBData= ko.observable(false);
    self.ShowCData= ko.observable(false);

    self.GetSearchDetails = function (data) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'some url',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {"PartnerID": self.selectedPartner },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.ErrorMsg == "") {
                    ko.mapping.fromJSON(result.data, {}, self.SearchResults);
                     var selPartner = $("#ReportType").val();
                     console.log(selPartner)  // the first time I get the selected valuer here.

                    if(selPartner=="1")  // show the the header and template of the first and hid the others
                    {
                        //Show A Data
                        self.ShowAData(true);
                        self.ShowBData(false);
                        self.ShowCData(false);
                        console.log( self.ShowAData());  //shows true
                    }
                    if(selPartner=="2")
                    {
                        //Show B Data
                        self.ShowAData(false);
                        self.ShowBData(true);
                        self.ShowCData(false);
                        console.log( self.ShowBData()); 
                    }

                    if(selPartner=="3")
                    {
                        //Show C Data
                        self.ShowAData(false);
                        self.ShowBData(false);
                        self.ShowCData(true);
                        console.log( self.ShowCData());
                    }

                } else {

                    self.ClearData();  // just clears the data
                }

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                self.ClearData();
            }
          });
       }
}
```

**Bindings**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    objvmSearchDetails = new vmSearchDetailsModel()
    ko.applyBindings(objvmSearchDetails, $("#GridContent")[0]);
    objvmSearchDetails.GetReportTypes();
});
```

**HTML Headers**

Here the headers changes based on the dropdown.  The LastCPR is only available in the second and third dropdown.   The `Gridsort` is a custom binding

The first time when I select a dropdown and click the search button the data and heading shows correctly.  Again I change the dropdown to the second option and click search it is correct.  When I change the dropdown to the first selection the header gets hidden not the data.

Why does the header get hidden.  I am assuming since A's observable is set to false it gets hidden.  In that case why does the template still show B's data.  (template code below).

So I tried clicking the search button to see if the A's data would appear but I get the below error.  `TextualEditBinding is another custom binding`.  LastCPR belongs to B's Data.  What am I doing wrong here?

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return (objvmSearchDetails.ShowBData()==true) }"
Message: Unable to process binding "textualEditDate: function (){return LastCPRDate }"
Message: LastCPRDate is not defined`

```
<!-- ko if: (objvmSearchDetails.ShowAData()==true) -->
<div style="display: none" class="grid_ccf_Lay_title" data-bind="visible:SearchResults().length>0">
 <div>
     <div >
                <a  data-bind="GridSort:'SearchResults.ClientID'">Child ID</a></div>  
   </div>
   <div>
       <div >
              <a  data-bind="GridSort:'SearchResults.InterActionDesc'">Interaction Desc</a></div>
        </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: (objvmSearchDetails.ShowBData()==true) -->
<div style="display: none" class="grid_ccf_Lay_title" data-bind="visible:SearchResults().length>0">
 <div>
     <div >
                <a  data-bind="GridSort:'SearchResults.ClientID'">Child ID</a></div>  
   </div>
   <div>
       <div >
             <a data-bind="GridSort:'SearchResults.LastCPRDate'">Last CPR</a></div>
        </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: (objvmSearchDetails.ShowCData()==true) -->
<div style="display: none" class="grid_ccf_Lay_title" data-bind="visible:SearchResults().length>0">
 <div>
     <div >
                <a  data-bind="GridSort:'SearchResults.ClientID'">Child ID</a></div>  
   </div>
   <div>
       <div >
             <a data-bind="GridSort:'SearchResults.LastCPRDate'">Last CPR</a></div>
        </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

** Template **

```
<script type="text/html" id="TmplSearchResults">  
     <!-- ko if: (ShowAData()==true) -->
            <!-- Lay -->
            <div>
                <div  data-bind="text: ClientID">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div >
                <div data-bind="textualEditDate: CorrespondenceDate">

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->


     <!-- ko if: (ShowBData()==true) -->
            <!-- Lay -->
            <div>
                <div  data-bind="text: ClientID">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div >
                <div data-bind="textualEditDate: LastCPR">

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->


     <!-- ko if: (ShowCData()==true) -->
            <!-- Lay -->
            <div>
                <div  data-bind="text: ClientID">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div >
                <div data-bind="textualEditDate: LastCPR">

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
 </script>
```

**Update 1**

I do have `textualEditDate` which again is another custom binding that just takes a date in MM-DD-YYYY format and converts it using momentjs to DD-MMM-YYYY format

**Update 2**

I got rid of the error by clearing the observableArray before the mapping and also moving the mapping after the if statement.  I think this is not the correct way. Any suggestion would be helpful

Changed code

`self.SearchResults([])` Clearing the observablearray

Moved this after the if block `ko.mapping.fromJSON(result.data, {}, self.SearchResults);` like this

```
self.SearchResults([]);

if(selPartner=="1")  // show the the header and template of the first and hid the others
{
  ....
}
''''
''''
ko.mapping.fromJSON(result.data, {}, self.SearchResults);
```

Now I need to find out how to stop the header from clearing after I change the dropdown to the original selection

Comment: check your response if lastCPRdate is defined

Comment: When I change the dropdown to the first selection the lastCPR does not exist.  Why does it still look for that I am not sure

Comment: I updated my question how I stopped the error from coming but not sure if it is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

`SearchResults` is an observableArray. So `SearchResults.LastCPRDate` is undefined, because `observableArray` doesn't have that property, rather I suspect individual items in your array have that property.

What does `GridSort` want as a parameter? Could it be the column NAME? If so, pass it as a string. Now you're passing a property that simply does not exist.

Comment: Yes ``SearchResults.LastCPRDate`` does not exist the observable array.  Why does it keep looking for it.  The first time I search the observable has these ``"ClientID":11abc,"CorrespondenceDate":"June - 2014".  The second time - "LastCPRDate":"2013-05-28T00:00:00" and going back to the first the it is not in the observable array

Comment: And the ``GridSort`` expects the column name.  This binding just sorts the grid

Comment: However I want to change the header and template data based on the dropdown when I click the search button

Comment: I removed the GridSort still I get that error.  Where can I be missing

Comment: You have a binding `textualEditDate: LastCPRDate` somewhere. That one is causing your error. I cannot find it in the code you posted though.

Comment: Yes there is a ``textualEditDate``.  I updated my code.  In fact all dates I have that custom binding.  I am have just one view model and the binding apply to the whole page.  I suspect that could cause and issue.  But on second thoughts the ``SearchResults`` observable array should get cleared and re-populated with the data from the ajax calls, unless it is not getting cleared

Comment: I updated my question.  I got rid of the error but not sure if that is correct